# MS Access Query to for Complex Issue

Tags: ms-access-2010, multiple-tables, cross-reference

I have several tables: SW_Report, SW_List, Manual_Install, Cloud_Install, & SW_Exclusion. SW_Report has a field Computer_Name (eg: CN1) & App_Name (eg: iTunes) where a row exists for each app installed on each user's computer (eg: CN1 - iTunes, CN1 - Adobe, CN2 - iTunes...). (SW_List has a field App_Name (eg: iTunes) and App_ID (eg: 1001). Manual_Install is a table built by another project team that has a list of Tested_Apps (slightly different naming conventions) (eg: iTunes 10.1_EN_US) & an App_ID (eg: n001) (it is not possible to just test to see if the App contains the name when running a query). This is also true of Cloud_Install (Cloud_App and App_ID - none of which are consistent with any of the aforementioned tables.

I have manually mapped the ID in Manual_Install and Cloud_Install to the their corresponding App ID in SW_List and titled them Manual_SW_Xref and Cloud_SW_Xref. What I need to do is build a query that looks at each App_Name installed on each unique Computer_Name, checks if it is listed in the Manual_SW_Xref and Cloud_SW_Xref and returns only a list of Computer_Name that have SW contained in one of the two lists.

Any thoughts? I need a starting point. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to test if a field exists in another field

```
 SELECT t1.field1 
 FROM table1 As t1, table2 As t2
 WHERE t1.Field1 & "*" like t2.Field1
```